# Button over Button has a different color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have two buttons. Its the same grafic on both. But if i place one button on the other button, the button on top will be a little more brighter.

```
<Button x:Name="btnMenue1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,360" Width="625" Click="btnMenue1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="36" Foreground="White" Height="340" RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.503" Background="#FFCBCAC8" BorderBrush="#FF0F0F11" IsEnabled="False">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" TargetName="Border"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnMenue1Text, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>

    <Button x:Name="btnMenue1Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,650" Width="310" Click="btnMenue1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="36" Foreground="White" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.503" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="False">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" TargetName="Border"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbMenue1" Foreground="White" FontSize="36" Text="Menue1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontWeight="Bold" Width="290" />
    </Button>
```

[Picture if button is over button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NauUk.png)

[Picture if button is not over button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J2Ks.png)

Comment: `Opacity:` `0.5+0.5=1`

Comment: To fix: Set `btnMenue1Text` `Background="Transparent"`

Comment: To fix: Set btnMenue1Text Background="Transparent" -> nothing Changed

Comment: So, if your `btnMenue1Text.Background=Transparent`, how could you get the result showing in your two pictures? As from those pictures, its background is obviously DarkRed?

Comment: In my code I override the background with the same picture, sry

Comment: `ImageBrush brush2 = new ImageBrush();
 brush2.ImageSource = LoadImage(bild);
 btnMenue1.Background = brush2;
 btnMenue1Text.Background = brush2;`

Comment: OK, don't override it in your code then, keep it as Transparent and then both buttons will have the same background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Opacity` for color blending.

So if you want something like a maroon color, use a maroon color, not a half-transparent red element on a black background.

*(To hack around the hack you could add a completely black element below your transparent overlaying element. Don't do this.)*